# Real diffeomeorphism preserving the space of Holomorphic vector fields

Tags: complex-geometry, complex-manifolds

Assume  that $M$ is  a  complex manifold.

Let $G$  be  the  group of  all (real) smooth diffeomorphisms $\phi$ of $M$  such that $\phi^* (X)$ is  a  holomorphic  vector  field for  all holomorphic  vector  fields $X$  on $M$. Is $G$ a  finite  dimensional  Lie  group?(With respect  to  a  natural smooth structure  on $G$).

Comment: Do you mean globally defined holomorphic vector fields? Many complex manifolds only have one globally defined holomorphic vector field: 0. For example, any compact Riemann surface of genus 2 or more. In that case, your group $G$ is the group of all diffeomorphisms, not a Lie group.

Comment: @BenMcKay  Thnks  for  your  comment. Yes  I  mean global  vector  fields.What is a reference  for  the fact you mentioned  for genus 2? Moreover what is  the  structure  of  $G$  when  $M=\mathbb{C}$?

Comment: Or  $M$ is  an  open  set  in the  complex  plane?  For  $M=\mathbb{C}$ is  there  a diffeomorphism different  from $az+b$ or  $a\bar{z}+b$?

Comment: @BenMcKay  Is  there a  complex  manifold  for  which $G$ is  small for  example  the  G  action is  not transitive?

Comment: Hurwitz's theorem states that for a Riemann surface of genus 2 or more, the size of its full automorphism group is no greater than 84(g-1). Any non-trivial holomorphic flow consists of infinitely many automorphisms, so cannot exist on a higher genus Riemann surface.

Comment: @DanielAsimov  Thank you very much for your attention to my question and your helpfull comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take complex vector space $V$, say of complex dimension $n$. Take a complex linear map $A \colon V \to V$ whose eigenvalues $\lambda$ all satisfy $|\lambda|>1$. The group generated by $A$ acts on $V-0$ freely and properly, with quotient a compact complex manifold $M=(V-0)/(z \sim Az)$, called a *primary Hopf manifold*. The group of linear transformations commuting with $A$ acts on $V$, transitively on a dense open set. These linear transformations descend to biholomorphisms of $M$. Any holomorphic vector field on $M$ lifts to a holomorphic vector field $v \colon V-0 \to V$ commuting with $A$. By Hartogs extension theorem, $v$ extends to a holomorphic map $v \colon V \to V$. Expand in a Taylor series, and apply $A$-invariance, to prove that $v$ is linear. Hence the biholomorphism group of $M$ is the group of linear transformations commuting with $A$. This group preserves the generalized eigenspaces of $A$, so these project to submanifolds of $M$ which are invariant under all holomorphic vector fields. Your group $G$ preserves the holomorphic vector fields, and therefore preserves their orbits, the images of the generalized eigenspaces. So $G$ is not compact, since it contains the invertible linear transformations commuting with $A$. But $G$ acts transitively only on a dense open set, and not on all of $M$.

Comment: Dear  Ben  Thank  you  so  much  for  this  very  interesting answer.